# ASP.NET: Is exposing RNGCryptoServiceProvider's output to the outside a security risk?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography

Is exposing RNGCryptoServiceProvider's output to the outside (in a cookie, for example) a security risk? Can a potential intruder gather any valuable information from this, like knowing what the next set of random bytes will be?

Comment: Only if somebody breaks its crypto. Not suffering from such attacks is one of the most important properties a PRNG must have to be considered cryptographically secure (CSPRNG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is designed to generate a sequence of random numbers that is not guessable and does not "leak" information.  I recommend using the [GetNonZeroBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getnonzerobytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method, to generate your next random number.

Comment: So you can't gather any information about the entropy or next sequence of bytes by looking at the output? I guess what I'm asking is if I should hash the output before handing it out. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanLundmark, No need to hash.  This RNG is designed to not "leak"  information.

Comment: I don't see why you'd use `GetNonZeroBytes` over `GetBytes`. It'd use the latter, and encode it with (url safe) Base64 where necessary.